# Rails layout inheritance documentation wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On the rails 3.2 release notes page (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_2_release_notes.html), it says:

```
Deprecated implied layout lookup in controllers whose parent had a explicit layout set
```

But I tried the following in my rails 3.2.6 app:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  layout "application_main"
end

class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @slideshow_pics = Event.get_intro_slide_photos
  end
end
```

with layouts `application_main.html.haml` and `home.html.haml` defined and when i go to the home#index page, I get the `home.html.haml` layout rendered instead of the other.

This seems to go against the deprecation so I was wondering, did one of the releases since 3.2.6 regress the deprecation?

Comment: Deprecated means deprecated, not removed--I couldn't quite parse the question, are you just confused about what deprecated means, or something else?

Comment: oh okay, yea i just got confused with what deprecated means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be even more clear than Dave above, "Deprecated" means: **Watch out, we're going to remove this functionality in the future! We're throwing this warning so you pay attention and you better change this soon as we are change how things work!**

It doesn't mean that the functionality has already been changed.